# Meaning of しょわー

Tags: words, meaning, usage, onomatopoeia, writing-identification

In the last panel at the bottom of the page, she says 「しょ__ー」.

I'm not quite sure as to what that last character is, including its use(s) and pronunciation(s).

I have seen this character in various other comics, and I think that it might be a sound effect/onomatopoeia (?).

[image: image with text I can't read]

What is it and what does it mean?

Comment: @japanesebeginner -- please ask that as a separate question rather than cluttering the one you already have gotten an answer for. Stackexchange uses a question and answer format meaning it works best when you ask something that can be answered altogether.

Answer (score 7):

> しょわー

I think it's an onomatopoeia of the fizzing sound from soda.

Comment: The second stroke of 「わ」 「ね」 and 「れ」 is sometimes simplified like this, and it looks childish or cute. A few handwritten fonts [like this one](http://www.flopdesign.com/font2/ryunosuke.html) have similar glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

My money's on onomatopoeia as well, as it's written outside of a speech bubble, like the sniffing sound くんくん and the gulping sound ごく, and it's in the same hand as those. We also see あー in this same format in the same panel as the little girl says 「あー！」.

That being said, while しょわー sounds very effervescent, the illustration makes me think it's meant to represent her shivering after drinking more of the sour beverage.

As said above, the last character before the chôon is a speedily-written わ.